# Permission denied (publickey) when trying to Git Clone

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, ssh

I know this is a common issue, however, even after spending an hour looking at threads I was unable to find a solution and therefore am posting here. Basically, when running `git clone`, I am getting the following error:

```
   Permission denied (publickey).
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
```

I do have a id_rsa and a id_rsa.pub in my .ssh directory, and the key matches up with the key I have on github as well under the ssh keys section. So that's not a problem. However, I realized I don't have a id_dsa file or any other file for that matter (except a knownhosts file). When running

`ssh -T git@github.com`

```
    I get Permission denied (publickey).
```

When running `ssh -vT git@github.com`, I get:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.123] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/parallels/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This is my output on running `ssh -vvvT git@github.com`

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.121] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/parallels/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/parallels/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/parallels/.ssh/id_ecdsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "github.com" from file "/home/parallels/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/parallels/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "github.com" from file "/home/parallels/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/parallels/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.30.252.121" from file "/home/parallels/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/parallels/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/parallels/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x7ffecad4c5b0),
debug2: key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7ffecad4aab0),
debug2: key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_dsa (0x7ffecad4ab50),
debug2: key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/parallels/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Something is weird but I can't quite figure out what the issue is. I have my keys set up using the GitHub documentation, but am still getting a permission denied statement. My keys are the same, as I checked my key on Github and made sure that the numbers are the same when running `~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Obviously the key do not match, because the `/home/parallels/.ssh/id_rsa` is rejected by github. Please add `ssh -vvvT git@github.com` output to the question. It might give some more guides.

Comment: @Jakuje done above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is rejected obviously. Run

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDHFxArGbqkeamciLR8kcsCwFYnagqNe/XG1Ehqhq092mwd/xHq89Pf1kVvC3OBOrvnb4g9l4LMKH28d8ZSJ2cDvtVwolMZBMzNB5HKid+7fNARQngY8t/WE+0ZuQjsA6OelgVx7QYBz893+0gKXdpALxs2Hd69s6Oy+vGphHmxsKG9PHe7l5StJBhMGbBTwDPcO/2YuZE7g5mh3VL/i3EfmkdYLBlBz1FD7/2J8npoYSdiGxUWvrbawfUw8fQwR6byM5AXBHWgJfWyGLKP6etvSQVTdutrp0GBjWn5GFlw8pKsb3R3N6h8CVKHKDAa4Hrf8wduOTwgT22n4zQ677Np
```

and verify that the string is the same as what you have stored in your github account. From the last update it looks like you stored there output of

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
2048 SHA256:xh0IVbIJmeYwdFWnvDQp/hB4OK+mjhlPyVXYQVpHTIA jakuje@jakuje-PC219 (RSA)
```

or

```
2048 MD5:46:e0:1e:c4:7f:de:12:66:ff:28:e6:36:81:cd:a8:b4 jakuje@jakuje-PC219 (RSA)
```

which is not the public key, but only its fingerprint (it is not enough). You need to store in your github account whole public key -- content of the file  `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Comment: So what I'm doing right now is `xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to copy the contents of is_rsa.pub and I'm copy pasting that as the key value on GitHub. It seems like you're saying that id_rsa.pub is not enough, but then saying to copy the content of the id_rsa.pub at the end and put that into GitHub, which is sort of confusing. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Public key is enough. The fingerprint is not.

Comment: Hmm..I kind of get what you are saying, but when I copy paste all of the contents of id_rsa.pub to the github key, it just gets converted to the fingerprint when I view it. When you say fingerprint, I'm assuming you mean " AA:BB:CC:DD..."

Comment: I think I just might not be in the right branch. When I do `git branch` nothing returns, so I'm assuming I should be in some root or other branch to do this. Could this be a possible solution?

Comment: I added the examples how the format should and should not look like. The `git branch` does not have anything to do with the `ssh`. Try `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa | xclip -sel clip`

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. SSH keys were fine, it was another issue. Thanks!

Comment: All I did was chown the directory I was in when trying to clone these repos. Pretty dumb error!